# Provide an http endpoint to other containers by local container ip address in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ip, microservices

I'm quite new to microservices and totally new with kubernetes. I'm designing a microservice which should provide some files to other microservices, all of them deployed as docker containers in a kubernates cluster and all of them using the same message queue. My idea is to place the URL (internal to the cluster and with the ip actually assigned to the container) to download files in a message on the queue. May it works or there is something I'm not taking into account?

Comment: Cotainers are ephemeral, and their IP can change. Use a service to expose the container.

Comment: but if for some reason the image has been replicated to multiple container, i need a URI which access exactly the one which generated this. Using a service is not an option here, i suppose.

Comment: If you have multiple containers and you need to get back to a specific one, you might want to look at using a stateful set.